# Transfer function of electrical network

Tags: transfer-function, bode-plot, laplace-transform, frequency-response

I need help with this problem. The transfer function that I found is ((RCS+1)/(2RCS+1)) , but then I cannot go further because the form of T.S is untypical. The typical form of this question is RC filter for which the transfer function is (1/(1+RCS)), but adding a resistor makes that complicated.

[image: The complete problem.]

Comment: What's stopping you doing the bode plot using that formula?

Comment: how should i calculate size and angle of this T.S ?

Comment: You know how magnitude and phase are defined, so apply that definition to the formula.

Comment: You have two partial fractions. Set \$\tau=\tau_{_1}=R\,C\$ and \$\tau_{_2}=2\,R\,C=2\,\tau\$ and let's set \$R=1\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$C=15.915\:\text{nF}\$ so that \$\omega_{_1}=10\:\text{kHz}\$ and \$\omega_{_2}=5\:\text{kHz}\$. Then:$$\frac{1+R\,C\,s}{1+2\,R\,C\,s}=\frac{1}{1+2\,R\,C\,s}+\frac{R\,C\,s}{1+2\,R\,C\,s}=\frac{1}{1+s/\omega_{_2}}+\frac{\frac12\,s/\omega_{_2}}{1+s/\omega_{_2}}$$As Andy points out in his answer, this is a low-pass (\$0\,\text{dB}\$) and a high-pass (\$-6\,\text{dB}\$.)

Comment: If you start one decade below \$5\:\text{kHz}\$ (at \$500\:\text{Hz}\$) with a nice clean low-pass \$0\,\text{dB}\$ horizontal line and then momentarily skip over to one decade above \$10\:\text{kHz}\$ (at \$100\:\text{kHz}\$) with a nice clean high-pass horizontal line at \$-6\,\text{dB}\$ beyond to infinity, then all you need do is place a nice \$-3\,\text{dB}\$ point at \$\sqrt{500\,\text{Hz}\,\cdot\,100\,\text{kHz}}\approx 7.071\:\text{kHz}\$ and then hand-draw the transition curve from the low-freq line, then through the midpoint, then to the high frequency line.

Comment: (Note that the zero is at \$10\:\text{kHz}\$ and the pole is at \$5\:\text{kHz}\$. You could just as well have used those in the square-root function. I just wanted to keep to the drawing line values, is all.)

Comment: thanks my friend .

Comment: @RasoulAkbari No problem. Hope the approach helps. Note that the \$\frac12\$ in the second partial fraction is \$K\$, the so-called gain. That's why the \$-6\,\text{dB}\$, in particular. +1 for the question. It may help others, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, using the voltage divider formula we see that:

$$\mathcal{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\text{v}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\text{R}+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}{\text{R}+\text{R}+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}=\frac{1+\text{CRs}}{1+2\text{CRs}}\tag1$$

Now, when we have pure sinusoidal inputs we can use \$\text{s}=\text{j}\omega\$ where \$\text{j}^2=-1\$ . So we get:

$$\underline{\mathcal{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=\frac{1+\text{CR}\omega\text{j}}{1+2\text{CR}\omega\text{j}}\tag2$$

Now, finding the magnitude function, we need to take a look at:

$$\left|\underline{\mathcal{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\left|\frac{1+\text{CR}\omega\text{j}}{1+2\text{CR}\omega\text{j}}\right|=\frac{\left|1+\text{CR}\omega\text{j}\right|}{\left|1+2\text{CR}\omega\text{j}\right|}=$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{1+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}}{\sqrt{1+\left(2\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}{1+\left(2\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}}\tag3$$

And for the phase function we need to take a look at:

$$\arg\left(\underline{\mathcal{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)=\arg\left(\frac{1+\text{CR}\omega\text{j}}{1+2\text{CR}\omega\text{j}}\right)=\arg\left(1+\text{CR}\omega\text{j}\right)-\arg\left(1+2\text{CR}\omega\text{j}\right)=$$
$$\arctan\left(\frac{\text{CR}\omega}{1}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{2\text{CR}\omega}{1}\right)=\arctan\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)-\arctan\left(2\text{CR}\omega\right)\tag4$$

Answer (score 6):

A quick look at the fast analytical techniques or FACTs gives you the transfer function of this guy in the blink of an eye. First, turn the stimulus off or reduce \$V_{in}\$ to 0 V: replace the source by a short circuit. Then, "look" through the capacitor terminals to determine resistance \$R\$ between the terminals. It's immediate: \$R=R+R=2R\$. You have the natural time constant equal to \$\tau=2RC\$ and the pole in a first-order system is the inverse of the time constant: \$\omega_p=\frac{1}{2RC}\$.

For the zero, you have to check what condition in this circuit would make the ac response to 0 V despite the presence of a stimulus? Well, if the series combination of \$R\$ and \$C\$ would lead to a *transformed* short, then the output would be 0 V. Just solve \$Z(s)=R+\frac{1}{sC}=0\$ and you find a root at \$s_z=-\frac{1}{RC}\$ and a zero located at \$\omega_z=\frac{1}{RC}\$. The below drawing shows the approach:

[image]

A quick Mathcad sheet shows the response of this filter where the pole is below the zero by a ratio of 2:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much my friend.I really appreciate your help and attention  .

Comment: @RasoulAkbari Verbal Kint presses for a good, general approach; which in my mind always brings up Dr. Middlebrook again in memory (he died not so long ago.) I always enjoy his contributions and you'd do well to can learn these ideas among others.

Comment: I think it is important to first "suffer" on arm-long equations with the Laplace transform - a bit like learning to count on your fingers before using a calculator - then learn the FACTs to go faster in determining transfer functions and writing them in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 4):

> *how should i calculate size and angle*

Here's a decent clue for the magnitude of the bode plot: -

[image]

Comment: I love the simplicity of this visual approach... Nice. There's a pole and a zero, not too far apart from each other (one is half the other.) +1

Comment: Thanks my friend.

Comment: IN this unique situation the pole/zeros are too close to each other to plot independently and the result here is they share a common inflection point at 3dB after LPF and 3dB before HPF per order. In @jonks example that inflection point =-3dB @ 7.5kHz , so that instead of 6dB/oct it never actually exceeds 2dB/octave since they are an octave apart.